# Scala framework to implement Spark dataframes

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am new to Scala & Spark. We are trying to convert a bunch of Informatica mappings (with complex transformation) to Spark using DataFrames. I was able to convert one of the Informatica mappings to Spark thru Scala & DataFrames where all the business rules are embedded within the Scala spark DataFrames.

Is there any Framework or methodology that we can implement so that all the business rules are separate from the framework. Whenever there is a change to the business rules, I don't have to change the framework and vice versa.

Comment: Can you give an example? You will get more help if it's clear what you need.

Comment: I don't want to embed all my business logic into the code. For eg. If I select 20-25 columns and put it into the dataframe and apply a transformation on top of it, the code looks really clumsy and not readable.How do I separate it out, so that, I can make my code more readable and easy to maintain for any future changes.

Comment: I don't think so. The apis for spark is the dataframe, this is what you have to use. It's up to your design if you need your business logic to be UDFs or UDAFs or use dataframes all the way. Pretty much this is all you get.

Comment: Could you select an example to illustrate your issue? As-is, the question is open ended and I'd be more inclined to close as "too broad" (to answer in this forum)